# Get json data from a posted URI in postman in java

Tags: java

I have been trying to get `JSON` data but it seems I am using the wrong syntax. What syntax is appropriate? This is my code

```
@Path("/jsondata")
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public JSONObject personal(@JSONParam("")JSONObject json) throws JSONException{
    String name = json.getString("name");
    String age = json.getString("age");
    String msg = "You entered two things";
    String doc = "{\"name\":\""+name+"\",\"age\":\""+age+"\",\"msg\":\""+msg+"\"}";
    JSONObject outJson = new JSONObject(doc);

    return outJson;
}
```

Am getting error on the fifth line at `@JSONParam`. What should i do. And how do I get the name and age from the json

Answer (score 1):

Well actually any JAX-RS implementation should be able to support JSON natively such that you are supposed to manipulate POJO instead of JSON object.

- When you set `@Consumes("application/json")`, the framework knows that the input data is in JSON format so it will deserialize it into the expected Java Object Type.
- When you set `@Produces("application/json")`, the framework knows that the result is in JSON format so it will serialize the returned Java Object in JSON format.

Here is an example from [this article](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/)

```
@Path("/json/metallica")
public class JSONService {

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Track getTrackInJSON() {
        Track track = new Track();
        track.setTitle("Enter Sandman");
        track.setSinger("Metallica");
        return track;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createTrackInJSON(Track track) {
        String result = "Track saved : " + track;
        return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();
    }
}
```

As you can see `getTrackInJSON` is annotated with `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` such that it can return the object `Track`, the framework will convert it into JSON format.

As you can see `createTrackInJSON` is annotated with `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` and has one parameter which is of type `Track` such that the framework will parse the input data to provide directly an instance of `Track` as parameter to the method.